# sql query that gets the difference between 2 recent rows for every row item that occurs more than once in a table

Tags: sql-server

Sql query that gets the difference between 2 recent rows for every value that occurs more than once in a table.
for example

```
book  value         date
A   4   2017-07-17 09:16:44.480 
A   2   2017-08-15 10:05:58.273
B   3   2017-04-15 10:05:58.273
C   2   2017-08-15 10:05:58.273
B   3   2017-04-13 10:05:58.273
B   3   2017-04-12 10:05:58.273
```

should return

```
A 2
B 0
```

Comment: mysql is not the same as sql-server. please only tag the database you are using.

Comment: @RaymondNijland noted. it's sql server. Thanks

Comment: Are you only concerned about the difference of value for the 2 most recent rows?  So if D = 5 on 2017-09-10 and D = 10 on 2017-09-12 and D = 20 on 2017-09-13, do you care about the 2017-09-10 record at all?  In your example data, B doesn't make this clear because, well, the difference is *always* zero.

Comment: @BaconBits yes i care about the date. it has to be the two most recent book recorded using the date column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
SELECT book, MAX(value) - MIN(value) AS difference FROM (
    SELECT book, value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY book ORDER BY date DESC) AS rownum FROM t
) AS a WHERE rownum <= 2 GROUP BY book HAVING MAX(rownum) >= 2
```

And here it is in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/06c70/2)

Comment: it's supposed to use the date column to get the two most recent records. This uses the minimum and maximum records.

Comment: I'm getting this error. "Column 'value' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function

Comment: That's what I get for answering your question without testing it. Edited my solution, and take a look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/06c70/2

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id_pk FROM [table] GROUP BY [fields you whant to compare by] HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

this select returns you the list of pk from element that are repited

so, in other select you migth get another Select like

```
Select * from [table] where id_pk in(
SELECT id_pk FROM [table] GROUP BY [fields you whant to compare by] HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)) limit 2
```

this is functional, still not good as i'm not analising complexity.

Comment: Thank you, but i don't really get the id_pk part of the query. I want to get the difference(subtraction) in column "value" of the two most recent records using the date column of course to determine the recent records.

Answer (score 0):

I would use analytic functions:

```
;with CTE as (
    SELECT book
        ,value
        ,LAG(value) OVER (PARTITION BY book ORDER BY date) last_value
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY book ORDER BY date DESC) rn
    FROM MyTable
)
SELECT book
    ,value - last_value as value_change
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
    AND last_value IS NOT NULL
```

`LAG()` was added in SQL Server 2012, but even if you're on a higher version, your database must have the compatibility version set to 110 or higher for them to be available.  Here's an alternative that should work on SQL Server 2005 or higher, or a database compatibility 90 or higher.

```
;with CTE as (
    SELECT book
        ,value
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY book ORDER BY date DESC) rn
    FROM MyTable
)
SELECT c1.book
    c1.value - c2.value as value_change
FROM CTE c1
INNER JOIN CTE c2
    ON c1.book = c2.book
WHERE c1.rn = 1
    AND c2.rn = 2
```

Comment: @A.Kiva Your error indicates that either you're connecting to an SQL Server from an edition prior to SQL Server 2012, or the database's compatibility level is for an edition prior to SQL Server 2012.  I've added a version that should work on SQL Server 2005 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

Add a rownumber before calculating:

```
create table #test ([book] char(1), [value] int, [date] datetime)

insert into #test values ('A', 4, '2017-07-17 09:16:44.480') 
insert into #test values ('A', 2, '2017-08-15 10:05:58.273')
insert into #test values ('B', 3, '2017-04-15 10:05:58.273')
insert into #test values ('C', 2, '2017-08-15 10:05:58.273')
insert into #test values ('B', 3, '2017-04-13 10:05:58.273')
insert into #test values ('B', 3, '2017-04-12 10:05:58.273')

;with cte as(
Select ROW_NUMBER () OVER (order by [book], [date] ) as rownumber, *
from #test)
select distinct [1].book, abs(first_value([1].[Value]) over (partition by [1].book order by [1].rownumber desc) - [2].val2) as [Difference]
from cte [1]
inner join
(select rownumber, book, first_value([Value]) over (partition by book order by rownumber desc) as val2
from cte) [2] on [1].book = [2].book and [1].rownumber < [2].rownumber
```